# What does the "=>" sign means in ARM assembly LDR?

Tags: arm, ghidra

what does this arm instruction means?

```
LDRB param_1,[r12,r5]=>local_b0
```

In particular I don't understand the "=>local_b0" part.

Ghidra decompiles it to

```
local_b0._0_1_ = *(byte *)((int)&local_b0 + iVar1);
```

but I don't know where the ".*0_1*" comes from.

Thanks!

Comment: umh, I'm starting to thinking that part is *not* part of the instruction but it's a comment from Ghidra telling me where [r12,r5] points...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like you've already figured this out, but this is a Ghidra markup. It can be enabled/disabled via `Edit -> Tool Options -> Listing Fields -> Operands Field -> Always Show Primary Reference` Here's what the help says about the option:

> **Always Show Primary Reference** - Option to force the display of the primary reference on all operands.  If a suitable sub-operand replacement can not be identified the primary reference will be appended to the operand preceded by a "=>" prefix.